# CUDA memcpy device to device error

Tags: cuda

I want to copy data in the device memory using cudaMemcpy, here is my code

```
unsigned char* red_src  ;
unsigned char* blue_src ;
unsigned char* green_src;

checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&red_src,   sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&blue_src,   sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&green_src,   sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));

//bla bla ..........

//initialization
compute_g<<<grid, block>>>(red_src, strictInteriorPixels,g_red, numRowsSource, numColsSource );
compute_g<<<grid, block>>>(blue_src, strictInteriorPixels,g_blue, numRowsSource, numColsSource );
compute_g<<<grid, block>>>(green_src, strictInteriorPixels,g_green, numRowsSource, numColsSource );

float *blendedValsRed_1 ;
float *blendedValsRed_2 ;

//set memory
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&blendedValsRed_1,   sizeof(float) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&blendedValsRed_2,   sizeof(float) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));

checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(blendedValsRed_1, red_src, sizeof(float) * numRowsSource * numColsSource,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(blendedValsRed_2, red_src, sizeof(float) * numRowsSource * numColsSource,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
```

it compiles , but when I try to run it , got an error at the `cudaMemcpy`, saying that:

```
tintin ~/programming/cs344/Problem Sets/Problem Set 6 $  optirun ./HW6 source.png     destination.png 
CUDA error at: student_func.cu:365
invalid argument cudaMemcpy(blendedValsRed_1, red_src, sizeof(float) * numRowsSource  * numColsSource,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice)
```

Anyone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not very sure if this is the exact reason of your error, but here's one thing that you're doing wrong:

You're allocating memory for `red_src` with a size of `sizeof(unsigned char) * SOMETHING`:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&red_src,   sizeof(unsigned char) * numRowsSource * numColsSource));
```

while trying to access it with a size of `sizeof(float) * SOMETHING`:

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(blendedValsRed_1, red_src, sizeof(float) * numRowsSource * numColsSource,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));
```